# How to deserialize JSON object on the client side

Tags: java, json, socket.io, gson, netty

I'm  using [Netty Socket IO](https://github.com/mrniko/netty-socketio) to send socket.io content from Java (well, actually Scala.)  I've tried several ways of sending a JSON object to the client:

- hardcoded String
- standard Java json library
- Gson library

Each time, when the data gets to the client, it's just a string that looks like a JSON object.  I'm currently sending it with:

`case class Data(message:String)` and `gson.toJson(new Data("what up"))`.  The object looks like this on the client:  `"{"message":"what up"}"`, although it's just a String and not a JSON object.

Any ideas on how to get an actual JSON object on the other side?

Thanks

Comment: what is on the other side?

Comment: JSON _is_ a `String`. That is the _whole point_ or serialization. At some point you needs to de-serialize the data...

Answer (score 0):

This works (JQuery):

`$.parseJSON(string)`